# Simple google map not working with external css and javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have set up the most basic google map view in an html page, following the guide [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), but I cannot get the map to show. I know this must be very simple, I've tried a lot of fixes, but it doesn't seem to work with linked css and js.
Please note that it works when I use the code in one page, without linking, but doesn't when I use external CSS and JS.
Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="css/mapstyle.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="js/map.js">
    </script>

    <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCUA3LnXH-B5z9GlGh_Gyrebh-xpQoYQMY&callback=initMap">
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var map;
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

CSS:

```
  html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #map { height: 100%; }
```

Here's fiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/up1gx4qm/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `initMap()` function when loading page like (if using JQuery):

```
var map;

$(document).ready(function(){
    initMap();
});

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });

    document.add
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/up1gx4qm/4/)

Add `script` of `google map` before your `map.js`. Because it need to load Google Map script in your `js`

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script‌​> 
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCUA3LnXH-B5z9GlGh_Gyrebh-‌​xpQoYQMY> </script>
    <script src="js/map.js"></script> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="css/mapstyle.css"> 
</head> 
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: tried adding this to the code. But did'nt work. It could be because my linking is not correct.  The css and js are in seperate files and I have linked them as shown above in the html. Is that correct?

Comment: You need add `jquery` lib into your `<head>` tag: `<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head> `

Comment: I tried that too, Doesn't work. I know it seems silly, but here's my code for html and the js and css is as same as your fiddle. What could be wrong?
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/map.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="css/mapstyle.css">
  </head>
   <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  <script async defer
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCUA3LnXH-B5z9GlGh_Gyrebh-xpQoYQMY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: Tried that too, used exactly the same code, god knnows why it isnt working. So I copied another code from the interent and edited it to suit my requirement. It is quite suprising though that it doesnt work when it works pretty well in the fiddle. Anyway thanks for the help. If you have any suggestions, please let me know, because I intend to explore this further when I am free.

Answer (score 1):

With your fiddle I get an error in the javascript console: `Uncaught TypeError: window.initMap is not a function`.  This is because the `initMap` function is wrapped in and local to the `window.onload` function, so it is not globally available as the callback routine for the API.

To fix it, set the "Frameworks & Extensions" in the fiddle to "No Library (pure JS)" and "No wrap - in `<head>`

Note that you have a typo in your posted code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="css/mapstyle.css">
```

should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mapstyle.css">
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/up1gx4qm/6/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: If I use pureJs only, how can I use jquery in the site? I need jquery for other functions.

Comment: No reason you can't include jQuery also, it just isn't needed for the posted code.